# Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax for every code I run

Tags: python

Over the last hour I have been doing the exercise 18, 19, 20 and 21 from the book 'Learn Python the Hard Way'.

And everytime I see an error like this:

```
File "ex21.py", line 2
        print(f"ADDING {a} + {b}")
                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And it's **ALWAYS in line 2** no matter which exercise I run!

Here is the code of exercise 21 if that is of any help:

```
def add(a, b):
    print(f"ADDING {a} + {b}")
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print(f"SUBTRACTING {a} - {b}")
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print(f"MULTIPLYING {a} * {b}")
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print(f"DIVIDING {a} / {b}")
    return a / b


print("Let's do some math with just functions!")

age =  add(30,5)
height = subtract(78,4)
weight = multiply(90,2)
iq = divide(100,2)

print(f"Age: {age}, Height: {height}, Weight: {weight}, IQ: {iq}")

#A puzzle for extra credit. type it in anyway
print("Here is a puzzle.")

what = add(age,subtract(height, multiply(weight,divide(iq,2))))

print("That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?")
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using python 3? format strings don't exist in python 2. Also, what do you mean by "whatever exercise I run"? Maybe you should try just having a few prints to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong version of Python. The 'f-strings' syntax is a new feature of Python3.6. If your version is before 3.6, it will raise error.
I try your code in Python3.6, and I got no errors.
If you are using earlier version of python, don't use the 'f-strings' syntax:

```
def subtract(a, b):
    print("SUBTRACTING {a} - {b}")
    return a - b
```

Answer (score 0):

The f-string is a new syntax introduced in **Python 3.6**. If you're trying to run a program that contains f-strings on Python 3.5 or earlier, it's a syntax error.

For compatibility with Python 2.6 to 3.5 I suggest using the `.format` method of string objects:

```
print("ADDING {} + {}".format(a, b))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can determine your Python version on command line:

```
python --version
python3 --version
```

or with Python code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```